# clearing different edittexts with different buttons while reusing same code

Tags: java, android

I have two different edittext fields, each with a 'clear' button to clear the inputted text. I can clear both fields like so:

XML:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fieldOneInput"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clearButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/clearTextField1"
        android:onClick="clearTextField1"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fieldTwoInput"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clearButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/clearTextField2"
        android:onClick="clearTextField2"/>
```

Java:

```
 public void clearTextField1(View view){
     EditText fieldOneInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldOneInput);
     fieldOneInput.setText("");
 }

 public void clearTextField2(View view){
     EditText fieldTwoInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldTwoInput);
     fieldOneInput.setText("");
 }
```

This isn't practical if I have multiple edittexts each with a 'clear' button. How would I go about clearing different edittexts fields using different buttons while reusing the same (java) code?

Comment: from both button , call same method . and inside that method , try  `((EditText) view).getText().clear();` . But if you are trying to clear all fields in the given layout, you  clear all instances of EditText from ViewGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using following code:

```
public class AbcActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //... your code here, to get button objects from xml file
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                clearEditText(R.id.editText1);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                clearEditText(R.id.editText2);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                clearEditText(R.id.editText3);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                clearEditText(R.id.editText4);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void clearEditText(int editTextId) {
        findViewById(editTextId).setText("");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method like this:

```
private void setClickListener(Button button, final EditText editText) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

And then you can call

```
setClickListener(button1, editText1);
setClickListener(button2, editText2);
...
```

**Note:** Avoid calling findViewById(id) inside onClickListener, do it just one time before setting the listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snipset to make code reusable

You have to call this method on button click. And pass edittext which you wants to clear and button on which you wants to clear edittext

```
public void clearOnClick(final EditText edtClear, Button btnClear)
    {

btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edtClear.setText("");
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well either way you still have to instantiate the buttons, this is obvious. One way that I can recycle my code and make it easy is I copy and paste a stock code, such as

```
    public void clearTextField*(View view){
     EditText* fieldOneInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldOneInput*);
     fieldOneInput*.setText("");
 }
```

And then proceed to use `Notepad++` (specifically the `find and replace` function to replace the "*" with whatever number `textView` you are on. Simple and effective. Besides this I suppose you could create a `public void function` similar to this and pass the `id` of the button into it like so:

```
public void ClearText(String id){
Button defaultButton = (Button)findViewById(id);
defaultbutton.setText("your text");
}
```

But I didn't test that code so don't fault me if there is an error or exception in there. Hope this helps!

Comment: the first snippet is actually what I want to avoid - it feels poor coding practice to copy and paste the same code. the latter isn't quite what I'm looking for either as that sets the text of the button and not the text of the edittext

Comment: Change all references to a `Button` in my snippet and replace it with `EditText`. That's all

Answer (score 0):

Use this for every text field

```
public void clearTextField1(EditText editText){
     editText.setText("");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whenever you feel like you need more than one click listeners for buttons,etc. in your class, just implement the interface View.OnClickListener.

Each view has a unique id that we assign to it. These ids are stored as compile time constants and hence can be referenced into a switch case.

*Note: This approach does'nt work if you want to your code to be added as a module.*

You can use answer by [naran z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37717275/6393514) and modify it a little.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = INVALID_EDITTEXT_ID; // say -1
        switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        id = R.id.editText1;
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
        id = R.id.editText2;
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
        id = R.id.editText3;
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
        id = R.id.editText4);
            break;
        }
        if(id!=INVALID_EDITTEXT_ID)
            findViewById(id).setText("");
    }
```